# Run a JavaScript Puppeteer code in task scheduler?

Tags: javascript, scheduled-tasks, puppeteer

So i'm making a twitter bot with puppeteer in visual studio code. I have finished the code which when executed will post a tweet.

I am trying to make the code execute everyday at 4:00pm with windows Task Scheduler. I've tried many different times to make the code run, but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions or solutions would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are running your puppeteer code through `node index.js` where index.js consists of your puppeteer code.

In Actions tab of Task Scheduler, enter the node executable path in Program/Script and Puppeteer code in Arguments field

[image]

and set the trigger to any scheduled time.

Comment: I can not express how this helped me. Thank you! :)